# Laravel belongsto relations get property problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have belongsto relation:

```
class Yetkiliservis extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'yetkiliservis';
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function bolge(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Bolgeler::class);
    }

}
```

when I convert the model to array everything is right. It shows relation.

```
$yetkiliservisler = Yetkiliservis::with('bolge')->get();
dd($yetkiliservisler[0]->toArray());
```

**result :**

```
array:22 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "vergi_no" => "1"
  "yerel_adi" => "1"
  "bolge" => array:6 [▼             <------------------------------------
    "id" => 1
    "bolge_adi" => "İSTANBUL"
    "ad_soyad" => "istanbul"
    "email" => "istanbul@mail.com"
    "created_at" => "2020-04-24 15:53:31"
    "updated_at" => "2020-04-24 15:53:31"
  ]
  "yetkili_adi" => "1"
]
```

But when I try to get by the property it shows null.

```
$yetkiliservisler = Yetkiliservis::with('bolge')->get();
dd($yetkiliservisler[0]->getAttributes());
```

**result :**

```
array:22 [▼
  "id" => 1
   "vergi_no" => "1"
  "yerel_adi" => "1"
  "bolge" => null          <--------------------------------
  "yetkili_adi" => "1"

]
```

Comment: Please rename this like conventional method `public function bolgeler(){`

Comment: I renamed it. But same result

Comment: If u use `dd($yetkiliservisler[0]-> bolgeler);` then it shows the same result ??

Comment: try `dd($yetkiliservisler->first()->bolge);`

Comment: A.A Noman: yes null

Comment: Christophe Hubert: result null

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't delete the old column name "bolge". So it confused with the relation I think. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

First you change the raname like this

```
public function bolges(){
    return $this->hasMany(Bolge::class,'yetkiliservi_id','id');
}
```

After you execute this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then first check `php artisan tinker;` relation is correct??

Then try this

```
$yetkiliservisler[0]->bolges;
```

Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: I renamed the model class name Bolge. then executed composer dump-autoload. I can get by array but not with the property.

Comment: What's it the problem??

Comment: I try to get bolge property in blade. But it is null. But it shows in dd();

Comment: I changed the relation to hasMany() . But it still null as property.

Comment: If you try this `$yetkiliservisler[0]->bolge`. It shows all properties of Belge

Comment: Update my answer and try step by step. It will work 100 %

Comment: I tried it: The same result. Before I never encountered with a similar problem.

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't delete the old column name "bolge". So it confused with the relation I think.  Sorry guys

Comment: You are most welcome. And I create relation always above description. So it should work 100 %